# BABY5 vs. BABYM1? How does the network decide which is the "right" protocol?

Tags: node, protocol, consensus

The Tezos [Docs](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/releases/september-2019.html) say:

> Any node running the May release, in case of a successful promotion
>   vote, will activate protocol 005_PsBABY5H, which contains a bug
>   affecting bigmaps in smart contracts.
>
> We advise users to update to this release so that the corrected
>   protocol 005_PsBabyM1 will be activated.

How does the network decide which is the “right” protocol?

Comment: and even if they force code software to use another proto, they'll also be subject to accusation of doubles on the "correct fork. (correct being the one the natural protocol chose)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happen at the network level is the combination of 2 phenomenons:

- First and foremost, we can expect that bakers (who voted for this amended protocol!) will run up to date software and therefore produce blocks in protocol `PsBabyM1` so very few blocks in protocol `PsBABY5H`will ever be produced.
- Second, even if there is people with baking rights who produce blocks in `PsBABY5H`, up to date nodes will hamper there propagation. Indeed, as it has been added in the code of `tezos-node` that instead of activating `PsBABY5H`, `PsBabyM1` should be activated, up to date nodes will accept and broadcast to their peers blocks they receive made in protocol `PsBabyM1` but reject and discard prospective blocks made in protocol `PsBABY5H`.

Answer (score 3):

Once a baker activates the BABYM1 protocol, BABY5 blocks are considered invalid.
Once a baker activates the BABY5 protocol, BABYM1 blocks are considered invalid.
There is no competition in this case and thus no decision has to be made regarding which protocol is the right one.